# Do we need to call set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE) before calling schedule?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, scheduling

Do I need to call `set_current_state()` before calling `schedule()` to schedule the next process from the run queue?

I have seen lot of code where the kernel thread function is using `set_current_state()` to set the state to `TASK_RUNNING` or `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE`.

```
set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);

while (!kthread_should_stop()) {
        ....
        schedule();
        .....
}
__set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
```

Is it necessary to call `set_current_state()` with `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` before calling `schedule()`?

In this example code, what is the use of setting the state to `TASK_RUNNING` after it comes out of the `kthread_should_stop()` loop?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you must call `set_current_state()` before calling `schedule()`, because otherwise the scheduler will not remove the task from the run queue (if you just want to potentially allow other tasks to run without going to sleep, you should be calling `cond_resched()` instead).

The task state you set depends on whether you want to be woken up by signals or not:

- `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` is not woken by signals;
- `TASK_KILLABLE` is only woken by deadly signals;
- `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` is woken by any signal.

Additionally, `TASK_IDLE` is like `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` but does not contribute to load average.

The reason that code is setting the state back to `TASK_RUNNING` is because the `kthread_should_stop()` might have returned true on the first iteration of the `while()` loop, so `schedule()` was never called (you do not need to set the task state back to `TASK_RUNNING` after returning from `schedule()`).

Normally, you will be waiting on a waitqueue, in which case you do not need to directly set the task state - instead, you can use the waitqueue helpers in a pattern like:

```
DEFINE_WAIT(wait);

prepare_to_wait(waitqueue, &wait, TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE);
schedule();
finish_wait(waitqueue, &wait);
```